# Javascript Object to array then remove element

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object, ecmascript-6

I have this object

```
Object {
  "87291": "valid",
  "1873681927": "valid",
  "nwq89j8jw0qj9": "valid",
  "oVFYfWIUOsONE6JyMGYAbnsPMAr1": "valid",
}
```

what i want to do is remove object based on key value and return as array.

i used this code :

```
    let attay = {
      "87291": "valid",
      "1873681927": "valid",
      "nwq89j8jw0qj9": "valid",
      "oVFYfWIUOsONE6JyMGYAbnsPMAr1": "valid",
    }


    let aar = Object.entries(attay)
    attay = Object.keys(attay)

    for(var i = 0; i < attay.length; i++) {
      if(attay[i] == 'oVFYfWIUOsONE6JyMGYAbnsPMAr1'){
        console.log("found "+attay[i]+" at "+i)
        aar.splice(i, 1);
        console.log(aar)
      }else{
        console.log("NOT found at "+i)        
      }
    }
```

this code worked okay but the output after remove element is like this

```
Array [
  Array [
    "87291",
    "valid",
  ],
  Array [
    "1873681927",
    "valid",
  ],
  Array [
    "nwq89j8jw0qj9",
    "valid",
  ],
]
```

expected output should be like

```
Array [
      "87291": "valid",
      "1873681927": "valid",
      "nwq89j8jw0qj9": "valid",
    ]
```

Comment: If you pretend to have `key/value` pairs in your expected output, then do not expect to use an array for it.

Comment: The "expected output" does not make sense; that's not valid syntax.

Comment: Also just `delete attay.oVFYfWIUOsONE6JyMGYAbnsPMAr1'` and then do whatever you want to the original object.

Comment: i thought about this but tbh i didn't try it cuz u'm using React Native.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding but it seems like you're over-complicating this. You want to remove the **property** from the **object**?

```js
let arr = {
  "87291": "valid",
  "1873681927": "valid",
  "nwq89j8jw0qj9": "valid",
  "oVFYfWIUOsONE6JyMGYAbnsPMAr1": "valid",
}

let removeKey = "oVFYfWIUOsONE6JyMGYAbnsPMAr1"
delete arr[removeKey]; // Remove the property

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your runtime is okay with the relatively modern `entries` (and `fromEntries`), then you can get what you want simply.  (Guessing that you're really aiming for an object output, not an array based on the syntax in your question).

```js
let attay = {
  "87291": "valid",
  "1873681927": "valid",
  "nwq89j8jw0qj9": "valid",
  "oVFYfWIUOsONE6JyMGYAbnsPMAr1": "valid",
}

let removeKey = "oVFYfWIUOsONE6JyMGYAbnsPMAr1"

let pairs = Object.entries(attay).filter(e => e[0] != removeKey)
const obj = Object.fromEntries(pairs);
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

the answer came from @[Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy)

```
delete attay.oVFYfWIUOsONE6JyMGYAbnsPMAr1
```

simple and worked like charm and also worked on React Native

Answer (score 0):

you could use `delete` this way if the key match with the propriety:

```js
const obj = {
  "87291": "valid",
  "1873681927": "valid",
  "nwq89j8jw0qj9": "valid",
  "oVFYfWIUOsONE6JyMGYAbnsPMAr1": "valid",
}

const key = "87291";

delete obj[key]



console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Why are you using `map` for a simple iteration?

Comment: You could just use `forEach()`.

Comment: `delete obj[key]` already searches through the object to find the key specified, there is no need to write your own iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the less supported `fromEntries` by using a simple `reduce`.

```js
let attay = {
  "87291": "valid",
  "1873681927": "valid",
  "nwq89j8jw0qj9": "valid",
  "oVFYfWIUOsONE6JyMGYAbnsPMAr1": "valid",
};
const remove = "oVFYfWIUOsONE6JyMGYAbnsPMAr1";
const res = Object.entries(attay).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => k == remove ? acc : (acc[k] = v, acc), {});
console.log(res);
```